# Show that $\frac{-4z^{-1}}{(1-\frac{1}{4}z^{-1})(1-4z^{-1})} = \frac{16}{15}\frac{1}{(1-\frac{1}{4}z^{-1})}-\frac{16}{15}\frac{1}{(1-4z^{-1})}$

Tags: fractions

Can anyone help me clarify how this rewriting is done?

$$\frac{-4z^{-1}}{(1-\frac{1}{4}z^{-1})(1-4z^{-1})} = \frac{16}{15}\frac{1}{(1-\frac{1}{4}z^{-1})}-\frac{16}{15}\frac{1}{(1-4z^{-1})}$$

Comment: the question is repeated :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402830/frac11-dfrac14z-11-dfrac14z-frac-4z-11-dfrac1

Comment: No it is not. This is the next part of the same equation.

Comment: Then, may I ask, what have you tried?

Comment: Are you familiar with Partial Fraction Dissociation?

Comment: No, i'm afraid not. Sorry that I am not responding, but I am trying to figure our the result using your help.

Comment: As Maazuls answer clearly illustrates, this question is not a repost. So why the vote down?

Comment: Maybe because it didn't show much effort on your part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=z^{-1}$

Then

\begin{align}
\frac{-4z^{-1}}{(1-\frac{1}{4}z^{-1})(1-4z^{-1})} =\frac{-4x}{(1-\frac{1}{4}x)(1-4x)}
\end{align}

Suppose

\begin{align}
&\frac{-4x}{(1-\frac{1}{4}x)(1-4x)}=\frac{A}{(1-\frac{1}{4}x)}+\frac{B}{(1-4x)}\tag{1}\\&\frac{-4x}{(1-\frac{1}{4}x)(1-4x)}=\frac{A(1-4x)+B(1-\frac{1}{4}x)}{(1-\frac{1}{4}x)(1-4x)}\\&-4x=A(1-4x)+B(1-\frac{1}{4}x)&\\&-4x=x\left(-4A-\frac{B}{4}\right)+A+B\end{align}

Comparing coefficients, you'll have $2$ equations involving $A$ and $B$.

$$-4A-\frac{B}{4}=-4 \tag{2}$$
$$A+B=0 \tag{3}$$

Solve $(2)$ and $(3)$ to get $A=\frac{16}{15}$ and $B=-\frac{16}{15}$ then replace them in $(1)$ and also revert $x$ back into $z^{-1}$ to get your final result.

Comment: That is clever. Thank you for your very thorough answer. I'm reading up on Partial Fraction Dissociation now.. (the same as partial fraction decomposition right?)

Comment: You're welcome. And yes they're both the same.